# Directly irreducible ring and central idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, idempotents

My question is mainly concerned with the characterisation of directly irreducible rings as defined on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_ring).

We say that a (unital, not necessarily commutative) ring $R$ is *directly irreducible*, if the following property holds: Suppose that we have a decomposition $R\cong R_1\times R_2$ with rings $R_1,R_2$.
Then $R_1=0$ or $R_2=0$.

My goal is to prove the following:

**Theorem:** Let $R$ be a ring. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $R$ is directly irreducible.
2. The *centre* $Z(R) = \{r\in R \mid rs=sr \; \forall s\in R\}$ of $R$, which is a ring too, is directly irreducible.
3. The only idempotents in $Z(R)$ are the trivial ones, namely $0$ and $1$.

---

I could show the following:

- $(2)\implies(3)$: Every idempotent $e\in Z(R)$ gives rise to a decomposition $Z(R)\cong Z(R)e\times Z(R)(1-e)$. Note that $Z(R)e$ and $Z(R)(1-e)$ are indeed rings with identity element $e$ and $1-e$, resp., since $Z(R)$ is commutative. The isomorphism is given by $r\mapsto (re,r(1-e))$, and its inverse is given by $(re,s(1-e))\mapsto re+s(1-e)$.

  By assumption, the only decompositions are $Z(R)\cong0\times Z(R)$ and $Z(R)\cong Z(R)\times0$, hence $0$ and $1$ are the only idempotents in $Z(R)$.
- $(3)\implies(2)$: Assume that $Z(R)\cong Z_1\times Z_2$ is a decomposition into rings with $Z_1\ne0\ne Z_2$. This would give at least four idempotents, namely $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$. But by assumption, $Z(R)$ has at most two idempotents, a contradiction.
- $(3)\implies(1)$: Let $R\cong R_1\times R_2$ be a decomposition into rings. Then $Z(R)\cong Z(R_1)\times Z(R_2)$ is a decomposition into rings. By the same argument as in '$(3)\implies(2)$', we must have $Z(R_1)=0$ or $Z(R_2)=0$. W.l.o.g. assume that $Z(R_1)=0$. Since $0_{R_1},1_{R_1}\in Z(R_1)$, we obtain $0_{R_1}=1_{R_1}$, whence $R_1=0$.
- $(2)\implies(1)$: This is similar to '$(3)\implies(1)$', but we skip the step '$(3)\implies(2)$'. Instead, apply the assumption directly.

So the real problem is how to deduce '$(1)\implies(2)$', or more precisely, how do we obtain a decomposition $R\cong R_1\times R_2$ from a given decomposition $Z(R)\cong Z_1\times Z_2$ such that $Z_i\subseteq R_i$ for $i=1,2$. The same problem arises if I attempt to show '$(1)\implies(3)$'.

Comment: You can prove $\neg (3)\implies \neg (1)$ just like you did $(2)\implies (3)$. Assume $e\in Z(R)$ is an idempotent that is not $0$ or $1$. Then $R=Re\oplus R(1-e)$. If $Re$ were $0$, then $e=1e=0$. If $R(1-e)=0$, then $1-e=1(1-e)=0$. None of these happen since $e\neq 1,0$.

Comment: @NDB Wow, I missed this. One needs only $e$ to commute in order for it to be a ring and for the isomorphism, not $Re$ or $R(1-e)$ as a whole.